# How many sections of a vector bundle send a point outside a divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $\pi:E\to X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle on a complex algebraic variety $X$, and assume $E$ has nonzero global sections; fix a divisor $D\subset E$ and a point $P\in X$.

I have the vague feeling that the following question has affirmative answer, but I am not able to prove it.

> **Q**.  Does the generic section $s\in H^0(X,E)$ satisfy
>   $s(P)\notin D$?

In other words: if we fix the point and the divisor, we should be able to send the point outside the divisor with "almost all" the sections.

I just tried to reason in the opposite direction by showing that 
$$V:=\{s\in H^0(X,E)\,|\,s(P)\in D\}$$
is not the whole of $H^0(X,E)$. But how to compute $\dim V$, for instance?

Thanks for any suggestions.

**Edit**. Leu us assume, also (see comments below), that $E$ is base-point free and no fiber of $\pi$ is contained in a divisor.

Comment: For a trivial line bundle $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, every fiber is a divisor, and you're unlikely to miss a given fiber with a global section.

Comment: Another thing is that your bundle may not be base-point free, and so if your divisor passes through $0$ in the fiber over a base point, every section over a base point will go into your divisor by definition of a base point.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for pointing this out. So we should add $P$ not a base point. But in fact all the relevant cases (for me) are base-point free.

Comment: You should also obviously add that no fiber of a bundle is contained in a divisor.